# Laravel Service Providers

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking for direction on how to code this out. I have a Html image in my welcome.blade.php with a url. I have created a php file that will accept a variable from my config('services) this variable is used to figure out what url to provide to the blade file and be used in the html image url tag.

The issue is I set up the ServiceProvider like the below but unsure of the next steps to get to be able to use the response from the class in a blade file. Is this even the right way to perform this type of work?

```
  {

    $this->app->bind(\app\libraries\organization_url::class, function(){
      return new libraries\organization_url_auto_set(config('services.eveOnline.org_number'));
    });

  }
```

Comment: why not use view composer to pass the data you need to that view?

Comment: Binding means when your app needs an instance of that class, returned object will be used for that code. But as you define your need; you can basicly use View::share or [view composers][1] as @lagbox said.

  [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers